# Daily number of questions on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, statistics, stack-exchange

Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering, how many questions are asked on Stack Exchange/Overflow on a daily basis?

Updating the recent questions page I've seen at least one per second.

Edit: I'm not sure if this question belongs here.

Comment: Short answer: too many.

Comment: "I'm not sure if this question belongs here" It does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a list of [all sites in the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). Stack Overflow is by far the busiest at 7600 questions per day.

[image]

Comment: ...and about 10% of them are good...[*Totally made up statistic*]

Comment: @Paulie_D 70% of all statistics are made up on the spot.

Comment: Note that that is an average, midweek (Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday) there are over 10,000 each day.