# How come I get new updates on Meta but not on Stack Overflow itself?

Tags: support, live-refresh

When there are new questions/new updates within Meta Stack Overflow, I get a ribbon saying "x question with new updates". How come I do not see those on the main Stack Overflow site? I have to continually refresh the page to see new questions or updated questions.

Comment: Could be related to https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/798506185532014592 - where one hour equals 6-8 weeks.

Comment: A guess: because there are [lots of them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333745/2564301). Something in the order of 1 every 10 seconds.

Comment: @Glorfindel hmm possibly, but I don't think I've ever received that ribbon on stackoverflow

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I can't remember as well, but I'm not as active on the main site before as I used to be. [This post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322824/4751173) doesn't indicate that the SO main page is exempt from live refresh.

Comment: @Glorfindel hmm very strange.. just a question I thought I would ask.. I mean it doesn't cause harm to press a button or 1 button-click to get a refresh haha

Comment: You do get the ribbon when you're filtered on a specific tag. Just go to for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java and wait a few seconds. Only new questions though, updates would just result in a permanent banner that is always out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main site is ridiculously active - it gets a few questions *every* minute. Now add edits and answers to that. Making all of them increment a counter that resets only when you click on it would not only terrify everyone with the thought that they have to handle all of this, but also consume too much bandwidth (as [Travis J pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338010/how-come-i-get-new-updates-on-meta-but-not-on-stack-overflow-itself/338014#comment413146_338014)).

On the other hand, Meta is much more calmer with 10-30 minutes between each new question, according to a guess off the top of my head and a peek to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions. Showing the counter there makes sense since there's ample time to take care of every new question.

Comment: You are correct about the traffic size, but I don't think that it was done to assuage fears so much as that it would be a very large burden on bandwidth without much gain.